# Unable to change Youtube-dl Download Folder

Tags: python, linux, path, virtualenv, youtube-dl

I am invoking youtube-dl from a python program on Debian. I am using virtual environments for the modules. I have setup my options and I am unable to change the path that the file is downloaded to using 'outmp1'.
I have tried to change it to a folder that was within the same folder as the source file and virtual environment with no luck, and I have tried just putting the whole path into the 'outmp1' option instead of the path_folder + '%(title)s.%(ext)s' Again with no luck. The file just keeps getting downloaded to the same directory that the python file is in.
Here is the code snippet where I am defining the options:

```
path_folder = '/home/user/Desktop/Music/2021Playlist/'
    yd1_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outmp1': path_folder + '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
            }]}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `outtmpl` not `outmp1`

Example:

```py
ytdl_options = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': 'Sounds/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'vorbis',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
```

You can find the list of all available options here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L128-L278

Comment: Wow I must be dyslexic or something. It's weird too that I wasn't getting en error, it just ignored my mistake and downloaded to root folder like nothing was wrong. Thanks for helping lol.